# Can we prove consistency of Euclidean geometry in Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, proof-theory

It is obvious that the statement that asserts consistency of euclidean geometry (in fact its formalized versions due to Hilbert and Tarski) is a $\Pi_1$ sentence in the language of $PA$ (Peano arithmetic). Is this sentence provable in $PA$ ?

Comment: I think that's what David Hilbert proved.

Comment: Hilbert's axioms aren't first-order. However, Tarski's are first-order and have he proved they have a decidable and complete theory.

Comment: @NotMike Tarski's axioms are essentially the axioms for real closed fields ($RCF$). I can see how $PA$ proves that $RCF$ has quantifier elimination, but why does it prove the consistency of $RCF$? My thought is the field of real algebraic numbers (which is a model of $RCF$) seems computable and should be somehow interpretable in $PA$

Comment: A positive answer is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261411/what-is-needed-to-prove-the-consistency-of-tarskis-euclidean-geometry). According to a comment, Tarski cheated by working in set theory so that $RCF$ clearly has a model